# mssql exec in procedure - how to build

Tags: sql-server

I have code like this:

```
declare @response nvarchar(4000)
exec [sql_server].[EC].dbo.GetReleaseContent '4.6', @response OUT;
print  convert(nvarchar(4000),@response)
```

I try add this code to procedure but I get error :( any idea how I can do it?

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_release]
AS
declare @response nvarchar(4000);
(
    exec [sql_server].[EC].dbo.GetReleaseContent '4.6', @response OUT;
    print  convert(nvarchar(4000),@response)
)
GO
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_release, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_release, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Start by removing the `(` from the start and the `)` from the end.

Answer (score 0):

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_release]

AS

Begin

```
 declare @response nvarchar(4000);

exec [sql_server].[EC].dbo.GetReleaseContent '4.6', @response OUT;
print  convert(nvarchar(4000),@response)
```

End

GO

Try this.